# Symfony2 Filter Collections in Form

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

We have User entity which has relations(OneToMany) with other entities. While building FormType for User entity. We have took associated entities as collection.

```
         $builder->add('sso_users_organization', "collection", array('type'=>new UsersOrganizationType(),'allow_add' => true) );
```

We want to only show the associated entities with filtering based on status "active".

We have tried filtering in below way.

```
$organizations = $userEntity->getSsoUsersOrganization();
foreach($organizations as $key=>$org){
    if($org->getStatus() == 0){
       unset($organizations[$key]);
    }
}
```

But when we are saving the details back, other records having status as "inactive" are getting deleted.

Please can anyone help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. $er is an entity repository of the type specified by "class". In this case UsersOrganizationTypeRepository

```
$builder->add('sso_users_organization', "entity", array(
    "class" => "Acme\AppBundle\UsersOrganizationType",
    "query_builder" => function(EntityRepository $er){
         return $er->createQueryBuilder('uot')
             ->where('uot.active = true');
     }
 );
```

Comment: this field is not select element, contains sub forms as collection and for collection type we cannot use query_builder.

Comment: My bad, didn't understand it that way.